# Why is jQuery 1.8 Not Working in Internet Explorer 9 as well as IE8 ? (IE9 most current version as of Sept 2012)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

This is somewhat of a general question, but I'm sure I'm not the only one experiencing issues with Internet Explorer (gross) and jQuery 1.8.

(**DISCLAIMER:** I know this is a VERY broad question, but I'm hoping to compile some resources for myself and future Stack users to use for troubleshooting, as I have not found any help thus far.)

**QUESTION:**

What are the reasons that certain events/functions built into jQuery would work PERFECTLY FINE in Chrome, FireFox, Safari, **and even in Internet Explorer 7 & 8** but NOT in Internet Explorer 9?

I'm well aware that I can emulate "IE8" on my page to get around the issue, but this does not SOLVE the issue.

Here's what I've done/checked so far:

- Ensured all `document.ready` code is included right before the
  closing `body` tag.
- All `script` tags have `type=text/javascript`.
- Removed any "trailing commas" in my JS - IE doesn't like them.
- All document tags (i.e. `<!doctype html>`, `<head>`, etc.) are correct.

Is there anything else I can do that will ensure/help Javascript and jQuery to run in Internet Explorer 9 at least as well as it does in IE8 (without running in Compatibility Mode or emulating IE8) ?

**UPDATE**

If I place my `<script>` tags to include jQuery and my custom JS within the `<body>` of the page, MOST of it performs correctly in IE9.

Comment: what, specifically, is not working in IE9 that is working in all other browsers?  Usually it's older IE versions that have that problem, but if your code works in IE7/8, as well as Chrome, Firefox, etc., but not IE9, that seems very strange. Could you post the code that isn't working?

Comment: are you testing IE7 and 8 using IE9's console? is the console open when you are testing IE9?

Comment: @Adam Make sure you have no antivirus/firewall software that prevents jQuery from loading.

Comment: @Everyone above this comment --> If I place my `<script>` tags to include jQuery and my custom JS within the `body` of the page, MOST of it performs correctly in IE9. I am testing in IE9 (current release) and when I tested in IE7 & IE8, I have those (current releases of each) on separate PCs. I'm not testing anything in a console/emulator. I have no firewall or antivirus that I can detect preventing the code from executing. See the one edit above in original question.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  This question is way too broad, especially since your issue is probably related to a single problem.  Post code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: 'certain events'. That indeed is broad.

Comment: It's hard to describe the particular problems because of the scope of the website. For example, I have a JS twitter widget that pulls in the latest tweet. This only works when my JS file is included in the body of the page, in the middle. If I include my JS at the bottom before the closing body tag, the script does not work.

Comment: Basically, after further testing, it looks as though only in IE9, the page stops rendering JS after a certain point. But I can not figure out why...

Comment: Provide a reproducible test case. Otherwise there's little to say.

Comment: Is there a reason JS would work if the `<script>` tags are in the middle of the page, rather than right before the closing body tag?

Comment: FYI - I think I found the solution: In jQuery 1.8, there was a bug in the core. "#12282: 1.8.0 regression – document ready is fired too early on IE 9/10." I am upgrading to 1.8.1 and will test accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, after further research, I found the solution: In jQuery 1.8, there was a bug in the core.

> 12282: 1.8.0 regression – document ready is fired too early on IE
>   9/10.

I am upgraded to 1.8.1 and everything seems to function properly in IE 7,8, and 9 (as well as in all "real" browsers)